# Which が is this?

Tags: grammar, particle-が

> しばらくその場を動かず無為に時間を過ごし、リヴェリアが怪訝な色を顔に映しだした頃。何かを察知したように、アイズ**が**剣を抜いた。

Could someone tell me what が this is? Is it exhaustive listing?

My translation would be: *As if sensing something, Aizu is the one who drew her sword.*

Comment: It can be interpreted as either exhaustive listing usage or neutral description usage, but the latter seems the case from the context shown here.

Comment: 普通の subject particle で、 "Aize drew her sward." でいいと思います。 「しばらくその場を動かず無為に時間を過ごし、リヴェリアが怪訝な色を顔に映しだした頃。」の次にアイズが何かするだろうと読者が予測しているなら「アイズは・・・」となるだろうし、その場に他の人物もいて次に誰が行動するか予測できないなら「XXが・・・」「アイズが・・・」となると思います

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the grammatical classification of the meaning of "が" to be able to tell you whether this is exhaustive listing or not, but I think your translation is spot on. It is a particle attached to the subject アイズ, and the use of "が" (as opposed to "は") puts an emphasis on Aizu, as opposed to other people in the context. "Aizu is the one who ..." captures this sense well.